# i have trouble with inserting image into database

Tags: jsp

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

> An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file: /insertimage.jsp
>   Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
>   49: try 
>   50: { 
>   51: itemName = item.getName(); 
>   52: File savedFile = new File("config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\image-folder\"+itemName); 
>   53: item.write(savedFile); 
>   54: } 
>   55: catch (Exception e)
>
> An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file: /insertimage.jsp
>   image cannot be resolved to a variable
>   49: try 
>   50: { 
>   51: itemName = item.getName(); 
>   52: File savedFile = new File("config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\image-folder\"+itemName); 
>   53: item.write(savedFile); 
>   54: } 
>   55: catch (Exception e)

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %> 
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%> 
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%> 
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%> 
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%> 
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%> 
<%@ include file="conn.jsp"%> <!-- to connect a database--> 

<% 
try 
{ 
String ImageFile=""; 
String itemName = ""; 
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request); 
if (!isMultipart) 
{ 
} 
else 
{ 
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); 
List items = null; 
try 
{ 
items = upload.parseRequest(request); 
} 
catch (FileUploadException e) 
{ 
e.getMessage(); 
} 

Iterator itr = items.iterator(); 
while (itr.hasNext()) 
{ 
FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next(); 
if (item.isFormField()) 
{ 
String name = item.getFieldName(); 
String value = item.getString(); 
if(name.equals("ImageFile")) 
{ 
ImageFile=value; 
} 

} 
else 
{ 
try 
{ 
itemName = item.getName(); 
File savedFile = new File("config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\\image-folder\\"+itemName); 
    item.write(savedFile); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
    out.println("Error"+e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    } 
    } 
    try 
    { 
    st.executeUpdate("insert into test values ('"+itemName+"')");     
    } 
    catch(Exception el) 
    { 
    out.println("Inserting error"+el.getMessage()); 
    } 
    } 
    } 
    catch (Exception e){ 
    out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    %>
```

Comment: there is something wrong with the number of quotes in your `file`

Answer (score 0):

There is a unnecessary double quote. To fix, replace

```
File savedFile = new File("config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\\image-folder\\"+itemName);
```

WITH

```
File savedFile = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\\image-folder\\"+itemName);
```